# Passing part of a va_list

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

How would I pass part of a va_list or copy part into another va_list starting at the nth element?

```
int main (int x, char**argv) {
    va_list clientArgs;
    va_copy(clientArgs, argv[3]); // get all input parameters after 3rd cmd line arg

    foo(clientArgs);

    va_end(clientArgs);
    ....
```

Or using the va_copy method ... ?

Comment: Any chance you could expand your piece of code to show exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: what is the context? `args` in this case is only one parameter, doesn't make sense to use it with `va_list`.

Comment: I updated the code, when using argv[3] I only ever have 1 element in the clientArgs, not the remainder of elements

Comment: `argv` is only *one* argument. It doesn't make any sense to use it with `va_list`

Comment: You have no `...` argument list here, so there's no `va_list` to copy.

Comment: You can name the first parameter of `main` `x` rather than `artc` if you like, but why would you?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a va_list which appears inside functions with ellipsis, but the example function doesn't use ellipsis, so the whole question is confused.  Re-edit — or rollback – would improve it, but it would be better still to have a function definition with ellipsis in the question.

Comment: I apologize as I may not have communicated my intention exactly. Foo in this case would contain the ellipsis. abelenky managed to understand what I was trying to do, luckily. I have marked his response as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code will not be portable, or even guaranteed to work (undefined behavior and all that)

However, it is possible, as the code below demonstrates:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void VarShowArgs(int n, va_list args)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Arg #%d: %d\n", i+1, va_arg(args, int));
    }
}

void ShowArgs_StartAtFourthParam(int n, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int dummy;

    va_start(args,n);          // n is param #1 (value = 8)
    dummy = va_arg(args, int); // Remove Param #2 from args (value = 1)
    dummy = va_arg(args, int); // Remove Param #3 from args (value = 2)

    // Show arguments starting at Param #4 (which should be value = 3)
    VarShowArgs(n - 2, args);  // Minus 2 because we removed 2 params from the args.

    va_end(args);
}


int main(void)
{
    // First param says how many more args there will be.
    // This function shows the values starting at the 4th argument (value = 3)
    ShowArgs_StartAtFourthParam(8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Arg #1: 3
Arg #2: 4
Arg #3: 5
Arg #4: 6
Arg #5: 7
Arg #6: 8
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it is the most correct for what I was attempting to do. I hadn't thought of just advancing the list to the point I wanted. I did, however, end up just using an array of pointers  and disregarded the va_list. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  I think I could've made my example clearer... maybe next time the issue comes up.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "part of a va_list"?  The question doesn't really make a lot of sense.

A `va_list` is an iterator object that allows you to iterate through the arguments to a function one at a time -- `va_start` initializes it to point to the argument after a specific argument of the current function, while `va_arg` gets (copies) the currently pointed at argument and increments it to point at the next argument.

In no case does the `va_list` encapsulate the argument list -- its just an abstract pointer-like object that refers to the argument list.

You can pass a pointer to the `va_list` object to some other function and have that function call `va_arg` to process some of the arguments.  After it returns, you can then call `va_arg` to process more arguments, but this isn't making a copy of the argument list in any real sense.

You can use `va_copy` to copy a `va_list` in order to have TWO iterators going through the argument list.  Each is then independent, so each will see all the arguments after the point at which the `va_copy` was done.

There's no way to create a `va_list` object that refers to anything other than the arguments passed to the current function as `...`

Comment: Once a `va_list` object has been passed to another function, it cannot be used again on return except in a `va_end()` statement.  Its state is indeterminate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You can't pass `va_list`s by value at all -- only by reference.  After the function returns, the `va_list` is wherever it was left, so if there are more arguments you can get them.

Comment: The C++ standard mainly defers to the C standard w.r.t `<stdarg.h>` (the extra restrictions are not germane).  The C standard says: _If access to the varying arguments is
desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as `ap` in this
subclause) having type `va_list`. The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to
another function; if that function invokes the `va_arg` macro with parameter `ap`, the
value of `ap` in the calling function is indeterminate and shall be passed to the `va_end`
macro prior to any further reference to `ap`._ You may get away with it, but…

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly.  The second argument to `va_start` should be the name of the last parameter before the ellipsis (...) in the function's argument list.  Using anything else leads to undefined behaviour at best.

To be able to approximate what you're after, you have to know what the values are at the front of the `va_list`.  You can use `va_arg()` to read them, and then pass what's left of the `va_list` to your other function:

```
void function(int arg1, char *arg2, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, arg2);
    int i = va_arg(args, int);
    double d = va_arg(args, double);
    foo(args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Clearly, if the arguments in the variable list are all the same type, you can use a loop to iterate over the first N such arguments.  Note that there is no way to find out how many arguments were provided; your code must 'know'.  For example, `printf()` uses the format string to tell it how many arguments were provided (and the type of each argument).

Comment: Right, but the issue I have is that I want the 3rd element in the ellipsis, not the third parameter in the function call.

Comment: In the example, the list of values passed to `foo()` would start with the 3rd value from the ellipsis.  Hence, given `function(1, "idsis", i, d, "catamaran", 3, "pink elephant")`, the function foo is called with a `va_list` that 'points' (loosely) to the `"catamaran"` argument.  `foo()` would need to use `const char *s = va_arg(foo_args, const char *);` to access it reasonably reliably.  There is, in general, no way to access the Nth argument (and the Nth argument alone) because the sizes of the items can be different, as in my example call.